# SharePoint jquery javascript does not run but works from console

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have the following code which works from console but does not work on page load. 
The page does not have any error.

```
<div class="nav-report-category">
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ms-listviewtable tr[class='ms-gb']").each(function(){
        alert('test 3');
    });
    var $mydiv = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-report-category")[0];
    var $liTag = document.createElement('li');
    var $aTag = document.createElement('a');


}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-report-category">
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ms-listviewtable tr[class='ms-gb']").each(function(){
        alert('test 3');
    });
    var $mydiv = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-report-category")[0];
    var $liTag = document.createElement('li');
    $mydiv.append($liTag);
    var $aTag = document.createElement('a');
    $mydiv.append($aTag);

}); 
</script>
```

Not sure what you are trying to do but if you wanted it in the DOM you have to also append it.If this is the thing that "was not working".

Comment: My bad. it's not working. I had the script in the console. I cleared the console and refreshed the browser and same result. I am not getting the alert in sharepoint. https://jsfiddle.net/9eojdk93/12/. The code looks correct from jsfiddle and from console window.

Comment: Try adding the above script to a text file and save it in a document library. Then edit the CEWP and add the url of the script file in the reference link. SharePoint likes to strip/destroy code if it is input directly into the CEWP.@Fuji-H2O

Comment: Cosmin: That's what I do. I put everything in a file and then put reference to this file from content editor web part. I noticed that their is a custom web part and the object may not be available right away but my understand is document.ready should take care of this. I added this https://gist.github.com/chrisjhoughton/7890303 but still no help. hmm

Comment: @Fuji-H2O if you try with an id based selector do you get the alert? So just as a test make a div with an id and then try the same .each function with the alert inside.Also try in stead of the alert to have a console.log or some other kind of notice (maybe append a text to the DOM) to see if the code gets triggered.Maybe something is blocking your alert.